# How can I optimise MoviePy for fast rendering?

Tags: python, video-editing, moviepy

I'm an experienced dev but new to video processing and I don't usually use Python.  I need to be able to quickly process large volumes of 30 sec videos doing things like adding logos, concatenating and combining clips, and overlaying titles and graphics.

Functionally MoviePy seems to work well, it has all the features I need but it seems incredibly slow. e.g. in one of my tests, running on a 2016 MacBook Pro (2.9 GHz Core i7, 16GB RAM) it's taking around 258 seconds to process and write a 30 second video with just a few of the modifications I mentioned.

I've tried running it on several different types of AWS EC2 instances (Compute optimised and GPU instances) but it's actually considerably slower than on my laptop (360-380 seconds).

So my question is, what are the considerations for MoviePy rendering performance? What hardware/platform/instance type does it run fastest on? Are there techniques for speeding it up (or things I should avoid that might be slowing it down)?

Alternatively are there any other libraries (any language) or services that might be able to handle this task quicker than MoviePy?

Comment: IMHO, the best way to reduce the time ofe reender is using GPU languages such as Cuda, OpenGl...

Comment: Thanks @AgapitoGallartiBernat do you know any Cuda or OpenGL libraries that could do the kind of video editing and processing that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I have ve found one setting that's sped things up massively. If I set the explicit FPS (to 30 in this instance) when writing the file, then it renders twice as quickly (even though this is the same fps as the current input files).

I'd like to know if there's anything else that would also help?

Comment: I found these library for editing videos. I think that will help you. (https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks @AgapitoGallartiBernat

Comment: @DannyS have you found anything interesting? I'm having the same issue here! (: